# how can i exclude a range of dates in my data set in python?

Tags: python, date, dataset, extract

I was wondering if there is a way to be able to extract dates, for example,
I want every day of a certain specific date:

```
from 2015-10-1 to 2016-3-31
from 2016-10-1 to 2016-3-31,
from 2016-10-1 to 2017-3-31, etc
```

I would like to select all its dates until the end of my data set

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how your data is structured? Maybe with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using pandas dataframe `df` with your datetime values as index as your table use

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=1096, freq='D')
df = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)

# select only JAN to MARCH and OCT to DEC
df[~((df.index.month > 3) & (df.index.month < 10))]
```

Comment: it works , now how can i select dates from April to September?

Comment: To select dates from April to September remove `~` sign from above code